# Circular Significance Testing

Tags: r, statistics, geometry

If I have wind direction readings from a collection of wind vanes, is there something like a `t.test` (or other significance test) that I can perform on the circular data?  I am assuming a normal distribution (which the data below is from).  I found the `CircStats` package, but figured I would check here for some additional guidance.

Some sample data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(unit=letters, wind.direction=c(99,88,93,99,86,90,101,109,109,91,86,94,106,92,99,103,110,98,107,109,93,102,92,99,109,85))
```

That one works fine using just a standard t.test since it doesn't wrap around zero.  But,

```
df2 <- data.frame(unit=letters, wind.direction=c(1,350,355,1,348,352,3,11,11,353,348,356,8,3,1,5,12,0,9,11,355,4,354,1,11,347))
```

doesn't since its circular mean is ~0 but linear mean is ~139...

Comment: Would this work: `df2$wd.scaled = apply(as.matrix(df2[,2]),1,function(x) ifelse(x>180,360-x,x))`; `mean(df2$wd.scaled` = 6.69.

Comment: @baha-kev some of the wind vanes are way out of calibration and I'd like to flag those.  so often there may be one that reads entirely in the wrong direction, which I would loose with your solution. (e.g. mean is ~ 90 with one vane reading ~270)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aov.circular`, in the `circular` package.

```
# Sample data (with two groups, to compare the means)
library(circular)
x <- as.circular( 
  c(1,350,355,1,348,352,3,11,11,353,348,356,
    8,3,1,5,12,0,9,11,355,4,354,1,11,347),
  unit="degrees" 
)
g <- sample(LETTERS[1:2], 26, replace=TRUE)
# Test
aov.circular(x, g)
```

Comment: Perfect! `CircStats` seemed a little more complex that I needed.

Comment: A quick followup: I can then generate confidence intervals from `mle.vonmises.bootstrap.ci(aov.circular(x,g)$mu, mu = aov.circular(x,g)$mu.all)` correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant to say:

```
> df2$wd.scaled = apply(as.matrix(df2[,2]),1,function(x) ifelse(x>180,x-360,x))
> df2
   unit wind.direction wd2 wd.scaled
1     a              1   1         1
2     b            350 -10       -10
3     c            355  -5        -5
4     d              1   1         1
5     e            348 -12       -12
6     f            352  -8        -8

> mean(df2$wd.scaled)
[1] 0.3846154
```

This would work if you don't have many observations near 180.